# Find difference between two big tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, exists, full-outer-join

I have two similar tables in Postgres with just one 32-byte latin field (simple md5 hash).
Both tables have ~30,000,000 rows. Tables have little difference (10-1000 rows are different)

Is it possible with Postgres to find a difference between these tables, the result should be  10-1000 rows I described above.

This is not a real task, I just want to know about how PostgreSQL deals with JOIN-like logic.

Comment: look on this [How to compare two tables in postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814597/how-to-compare-two-tables-in-postgres) and this to speed up the diff [How can I speed up a diff between tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337871/how-can-i-speed-up-a-diff-between-tables)

Answer (score 40):

[**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) seems like the best option.

`tbl1` is the table with surplus rows in this example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.col = tbl1.col);
```

If you don't know which table has surplus rows or both have, you can either repeat the above query after switching table names, or:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl1
FULL   OUTER JOIN tbl2 USING (col)
WHERE  tbl2 col IS NULL OR
       tbl1.col IS NULL;
```

Overview over basic techniques in a later post:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Aside: The data type [`uuid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) is efficient for md5 hashes:

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number/8335376#8335376)
- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684)

Answer (score 7):

To augment existing answers I use the `row()` function for the join condition. This allows you to compare entire rows. E.g. my typical query to see the symmetric difference looks like this

```
select *
from tbl1
full outer join tbl2 
    on row(tbl1) = row(tbl2)
where tbl1.col is null
or    tbl2.col is null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the difference without knowing which table has more rows than other, you can try this option that get all rows present in either tables:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B) 
  UNION
SELECT * FROM B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A)
```

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, NOT IN with a subquery takes a very long time. I'd do it with an inclusive join:

```
DELETE FROM table1 where ID IN (
SELECT id FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 on table1.hashfield = table2.hashfield
WHERE table2.hashfield IS NULL)
```

And then do the same the other way around for the other table.

Comment: Note that `NOT IN` is different in principal from `NOT EXISTS`. `NULL` handling is different, which makes `NOT IN` more expensive.